# PHP snmp work with one connection

Tags: php, snmp

Is there any way to make one connection and work with it?

Now I have this:

```
snmp2_get("ip", "public", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
snmp2_get("ip", "public", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0");
```

Is there any function to make one connection and work with it or how I can put multi OIDS?

Answer (score 0):

SNMP over UDP, the default setup, is *connectionless* to begin with.  The PHP functions do not provide a means of generating a "handle" that can be reused; typically, you would create your own wrapper if you wanted this functionality.

Note, however, that PHP 5.4 introduced the "SNMP" *class* (see [the documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.snmp.php)), which would allow you to do exactly what you want.

For example:

```
$session = new SNMP( SNMP::VERSION_2C, "127.0.0.1", "public" );
$value1 = $session->get( ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0" );
$value2 = $session->get( ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0" );
```